# linq to sql string property contains queryparam array

Tags: .net, linq

I have queryparams dto `public string[] queryname {get;set;};`

1. if queryname="a" query all name contains "a" data id like 1,4
2. if queryname="b","c" query all name contains "b,c" data id like 4,5

but `var list = db.user.Where(p=>queryname.Contains(p.name));`

Now i pass queryname="b","c" query id like 2,3,4,5 ,i hope query id like 4,5 data list ,**i want linq to sql code how to coding**.

```
|  user table  |       
|  id  | name  |
|  --  | --    |
| 1    | a     |
| 2    | b     |
| 3    | c     |
| 4    | a,b,c |
| 5    | b,c,d |
```

Comment: i hope  **db.user.All(x => x.name.Contains(queryname))****db.user.Any(x => x.name.Contains(queryname))**

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5uNrbQ)

You can use [Intersect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it.

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences.

```
    var queryname = "b,c";
    var data = new []
    {
        new User { UserId = 1, name = "a" },
        new User { UserId = 2, name = "b" },
        new User { UserId = 3, name = "c" },
        new User { UserId = 4, name = "a,b,c" },
        new User { UserId = 5, name = "b,c,d" }

    };      

    var paramArray = queryname.Split(',');
    var result  = data.Where(p => paramArray.Intersect(p.name.Split(',')).Count() == paramArray.Count());
    foreach(var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine(item.UserId);
```

**Output**

```
4
5
```

Comment: may be, you can put ``queryname.Split(',')`` in variable and use it.

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my answer, please take a look at.

Comment: yeah it's for solution and factorization ;)

Comment: @Phong p.name.Split(',') throw error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "System.String [] Split (Char [])", so it cannot be converted to a stored expression. **my code is linq to sql**